# Compare HKSample with another HKSample to prevent duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, healthkit

[Swift 3.0]

I am trying to retrieve an `HKSample` from `HealthKit` to add data to my application and would also like to update the application whenever HealthKit is.

I have added an `HKObserverQuery` and it works. However, it does not check whether the `HKSample` already exists in my application before it adds it and continuously adds the sample to my application.

How can I check if an `HKSample` with identical properties already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKSample` inherits from `HKObject`.

All `HKObject` instances have a `uuid` property (in Swift) to uniquely identify that object.

So, when you query, you'll need to compare what you have already with what's new by `uuid`. Any you don't find in what you have already is new.

Docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkobject).